Struggling with flow error
I'm working on a flow for an email alert for work. I'm attempting to have the alert send an email to account managers when a bill is 31 days past due (we keep it in the billed status for reference when it is unpaid). The formula below is one that I used to set up the alert.
    TODAY() - 31 >= {!$Record.Date_Due__c} && TEXT({!$Record.Status__c} = 'Billed')

I am getting "The formula expression is invalid: Field $Record is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions." as an error code. This helped with the second record but unfortunately with the first one if I put it as Text the formula is waiting for a date, if I put it as date it is expecting 3 different arguments and if I encapsulate it all as text I get the same error code.
It is my first time doing a flow so I figured it would be a good idea to reach out here for help trouble shooting this.
Thank you in advance!

You can use ISPICKVAL

Determines if the value of a picklist field is equal to a text literal you specify.

So your formula would be like this
TODAY() - 31 >= {!$Record.Date_Due__c} && ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status__c} ,'Billed')


Thank you so much! This seems to have fixed the issue :) I appreciate it
